# creating Subdomain in Xampp doesn't work

Tags: apache, xampp, subdomain

I made a subdomain on Localhost over Xampp with following code in **httpd-vhosts.conf** (guide from different sources)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 (uncommented by removing #)

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
     ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/sub
     ServerName sub.localhost.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and following code into **hosts** of Windows/System32/drivers/etc/

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 sub.localhost
```

now the problem is subdomains are not working. One more thing I just noticed that when I start apache service in Xampp Control Panel, it has set the port as 80,443 for Apache which is good but as soon as I hit localhost in browser it changes port to different ports like 52352 etc. I also tried to setting up code in **hosts** file as

```
127.0.0.1:80 localhost
127.0.0.1:80 sub.localhost
```

but not working. I tried many other things but all in vein. While a month before I created successfully in the same Xampp Installation. off course i have created **sub** directory in htdocs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have this line uncommented in **httpd.conf**

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Remove this line in **httpd-vhosts.conf** (or comment it out):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Make sure you have a blank line at the end of both **httpd-vhosts.conf** and **hosts**, and make sure you're using tabs to separate IPs with their associated domains in the **hosts** file.

Make sure another application is not using ports 80, 443 (Skype for example).

Ultimately, restart your Apache server.

Comment: I Love you Man!!! I just commented NameVirtualHost *:80 and it worked. Although i tried many other things including this but at that time it didn't work. Thanks Buddy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create sub directory, *emphasized text*127.0.0.1:80 localhost*emphasized text*
the settings back to original and change only *emphasized text*DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/sub*emphasized text*